# Jinja2 if variable is defined set variable from Ansible defaults which references variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

In an Ansible role I am testing inside an Jinja2 template if a variable is defined. If it is defined, a variable from Ansible's defaults/main.yml should be set which references this variable.

This works fine as long as the variable which gets tested in the Jinja2 template is defined. If it is not, Ansible complains about an undefined variable.

Example role files:

```
$ cat defaults/main.yml
---
database_name: "prefix-{{ database }}"

$ cat tasks/main.yml 
---
- name: Deploy config
  template:
    src: config.j2
    dest: /opt/config
    mode: 0644

$ cat templates/config.j2 
# this works
{% if database is defined %}
Database={{ database }}
{% endif %}

# this is broken
{% if database is defined %}
Database={{ database_name }}
{% endif %}
```

Using the variable directly (see "this works" above) after testing if it exists works just fine.
How can I make the use of the variable in defaults/main.yml work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: in `defaults/main.yml`

```yaml
database_name: "prefix-{{ database | default('db_does_not_exist') }}"
```

You can read ansible and jinja2 code to understand clearly why, but basically, Jinja2 tries to read your var at interpretation time, even inside your if condition which turns out to be false, and finds an other var that it tries to interpret again which is undefined.

The above default value will never be used in your case but will prevent your template from firing this error (or any other task using it)